# Loading A Torrent From Magnet Link In MonoTorrent

Tags: c#, mono, monotorrent

I'm currently trying to load a torrent into monotorrent using a magnet link. According to what I've found via google this should work:

```
TorrentManager manager = new TorrentManager(InfoHash.FromMagnetLink(magnet),
    savePath, new TorrentSettings());
```

But all I keep getting is an error like this:

> Argument 1: Cannot convert form MonoTorrent.InfoHash to MonoTorrent.Common.Torrent

Does anyone have any idea how i can solve this error?